# Rails - get all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `Website` model that `has_many :links`, and `Link` model that has `number_of_clicks` attribute.

How to get all `number_of_clicks` for every website in my database?

Comment: Something like this: `Link.sum(:number_of_clicks).group('website_id')`

Comment: you mean a list of websites, and their number of clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the model

```
Website.joins(:links).select("websites.id, links.number_of_clicks")
```

Comment: That would actually work! 
It occured that I forgot to mention that my `link` model is not directly connected with `website` model (`has_many, through:`) so I ended up doing:
`Website.all.joins(:links).pluck('links.number_of_clicks')` and that gave me exactly what I wanted! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great,  you don't need `.all` you can ommit that